# Java Generics and Functions

Tags: java, function, object, generics, treemap

I have a function

```
public static void printTreeMap (TreeMap <Object, ArrayList> map, PrintStream ps)
```

and a TreeMap:

```
TreeMap <Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>> tm = new TreeMap<>();
```

When I'm trying to call `printTreeMap` like that: `printTreeMap(tm, System.out);`, I get an exception

> The method `printTreeMap(TreeMap<Object,ArrayList>, PrintStream)` in the type task_v7 is not applicable for the arguments `(TreeMap<Integer,ArrayList<MyClass>>, PrintStream)`  Java(67108979)

How can I fix it?

Comment: `TreeMap <Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>>` **is not** a subtype of `TreeMap<Object, ArrayList>`. The latter would allow `map.put("Foo", List.of("Foo", "Bar"))`, the former would not. Those types aren't compatible.

Comment: @Polygnome so how should I define ```printTreeMap```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest this approach. Note that for general  methods of this type there is no a priori knowledge of those types. Therefore, this relies solely on the types involved overriding `toString()`.

```
public static <T,U> void printTreeMap(TreeMap<T,  ArrayList<U>> tm, PrintStream st) {
     tm.forEach((k,v)-> {
          st.println(k);
          for (U e : v) {
              st.println("  " + e);
          }
     });
}
```

Note that T and U need not be different as both could be the same type.

Here is an example.

```
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>> tm = new TreeMap<>();
tm.put(10, new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new MyClass("Alpha"), new MyClass("Beta"))));
tm.put(30, new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new MyClass("Gamma"), new MyClass("Delta"))));

printTreeMap(tm, System.out);
```

Prints

```
10
  Alpha
  Beta
30
  Gamma
  Delta
```

The class

```
class MyClass {
    String a;
    
    public MyClass(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

A more versatile approach for any Map of Lists would be the following:

```
public static <L extends List<?>, M extends Map<?,L>> void printMapOfLists(M tm,
        PrintStream st) {
    tm.forEach((k, v) -> {
        st.println(k);
        for (Object e : v) {
            st.println("  " + e);
        }
    });
}
```